# Multiple archives for cpt, taxonomies, terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, archive-template

I have a CPT "corso"

I have more taxonomy for this CPT (argomento1, argomento2, ...)

I've terms on them.

Example:

```
Corsi
-argomento1
--mat
---post1
--geometry
---post2
-argomento2
--grammar
---post3
--story
---post4
```

I would have more archives and show like this:

www.site.com\corsi  (archive-corsi.php I think)

```
-argomento1
--mat
---post1
--geometry
---post2
-argomento2
--grammar
---post3
--story
---post4
```

www.site.com\corsi\argomento1   (taxonomy-slug.php I think)

```
--mat
---post1
--geometry
---post2
```

www.site.com\corsi\argomento1\mat   ( ???? )

```
---post1
```

If possibile somethink I can use for future post_type and taxonomy only changing few parameters.

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but if you're asking about the template that would be used by the term, it would be taxonomy-slug-term.php.

So for your taxonomy, the default template for the taxonomy would be taxonomy-argomento1.php

Each of the term archives would use this same template, unless they have a specific template specified.  For example, if you want a specific template for the "geometry" term, the template name would be 'taxonomy-argomento1-geometry.php

What is unclear to me is if argomento1 and argomento2 are actually different custom taxonomies or if they are terms within the same taxonomy.  If they are terms, the template format would be taxonomy-taxname-argomento1.php etc.

Comment: I think this post might help -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types

Comment: I will try to adapt it for what I need.
If im not good I retry asking here.

Thank's for your time

Comment: No problem. Good luck!