# flush_rewrite_rules() not working on updating Settings API

Tags: rewrite-rules, settings-api

I'm providing a checkbox to my plugin Settings API to enable/disable certain Rewrite rules to my plugins CPT. I want to flush the rewrite rules when the specific setting is changed. So I did the following:

```
function my_flush_rules_while_rewrite_changed( $old_values, $new_values ) {
    if( $old_values['rewrite_url'] != $new_values['rewrite_url'] ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        //echo "Rewrite rules flushed";
        //exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'update_option_my_settings', 'my_flush_rules_while_rewrite_changed', 10, 2 );
```

It's not flushing the rewrite rules. Though I tested without the conditions, and tested that the `echo`d text is displayed if used with `exit()`. So, I'm sure, the function is being called, but sad part is, it's NOT WORKING.

[image: Flush the rewrite rules]

I thought it's the Rewrite Rules plugin's problem, but the actual rewriting isn't working without saving Permalink changes. So it's actually a problem with my code - it's not working.

But why?

Comment: are you adding the new rules before flushing? It's not just emptying the rules, its rebuilding them from whatever is currently registered.

Comment: Yes, I first tried with `false`, then tried the hard flush. FYI, I added filter to `post_type_link` and `rewrite_rules_array` like this [QA](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/39500/22728).

Comment: It's more likely that the issue is not that the `flush_rewrite_rules` is not flushing rules, but that your new rules aren't present when the flush occurs. I can't verify that without seeing all of your code though. A hard flush will write to .htaccess, so a simple test to see if it's actually flushing is to empty that file and see if it's rebuilt after the flush.

Comment: FYI, here is my last code: https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/commit/1dc698507a4f89c024508fa077247de16b0c6350

Comment: Are you certain the filter is applied when the rules are flushed? You add the filter in an `if` conditional, have you verified it passes that test in this specific case? This issue is almost always a result of the order in which you are doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flush_rewrite_rules` *is* firing, but it's too late; the previous rewrite setting has already determined your `register_post_type` args at the start of the request, so you're just flushing the "old" rules.

You could try re-registering the post type just before flushing, but I'm not sure of the wider implications or even if this will work.

If it were me, I'd use the logic you've already got to stash a flag in the settings, then handle on the subsequent request:

```
function my_flush_rules_while_rewrite_changed( $new_values, $old_values ) {
    if( empty( $new_values['rewrite_url'] ) && ! empty( $old_values['rewrite_url'] ) || ! empty( $new_values['rewrite_url'] ) && empty( $old_values['rewrite_url'] ) ) {
        $new_values['flush_rewrite_rules'] = true;
    }

    return $new_values;
}

add_filter( 'pre_update_option_my_custom_settings', 'my_flush_rules_while_rewrite_changed', 11, 2 );
```

And then as an example:

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    $settings = get_option( 'my_custom_settings' );
    if ( ! empty( $settings['flush_rewrite_rules'] ) ) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        unset( $settings['flush_rewrite_rules'] );
        update_option( 'my_custom_settings', $settings );
    }
});
```

Comment: It's the answer. But isn't it be a resource-heavy workaround than asking the user to do flush 'em manually? I'm simply concerned about the hooking into `init`.

Comment: I don't think the expense is notable. The rules are only flushed on next request, settings are autoloaded. You could use admin_init instead, that should be fine