# Custom post type and taxonomy same slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have this cpt and taxonomy:

```
Portfolio (CPT)
Portfolio Categories (Taxonomy)
```

Now, I want to establish this permalink structure:

```
/portfolio/portfolio-category
/portfolio/portfolio-category/portfolio-post
/portfolio/portfolio-category/page/2
```

So far, I've achieved to make portfolio categories and single items work, but pagination isn't working. I'm getting 404 or redirected to a page with a similar slug to "page".

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried flushing the permalinks ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types)