# Is it possible to have dedicated page for parent/child taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've been working non-stop on this for the past few days. I have a post type, floorplan, which has a hierarchical taxonomy called County. Each County taxonomy has child taxonomies with the names of communities within each county, which I've been able to apply to the post permalinks by following [This Guide](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types?rq=1). So my post urls are now floorplans/{parent-county}/{child-county}/{the-floorplan}

Now, I have a custom county-taxonomy.php template that displays all posts of this type that have the county taxonomy assigned. The url is floorplans/{parent-county} where parent county is the parent taxonomy. This template will also display if you navigate to the url floorplans/{child-county} where child-county is the child taxonomy.

HOWEVER, if I try to navigate to floorplans/{parent-county}/{child-county}, I get a 404.

So my basic question, is it possible to modify the permalink of the taxonomy page such that it includes both parent and child?