Add URL parameter to nav links based on domain
I use a suite of third party platforms and want to automatically add a ?source=web-nav parameter based on the link's domain. Is it possible to do this via functions.php?

You may follow this article that have solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types/39862#39862

I don't think that question is related to this one. Note that it'll be assumed you're using standard WordPress nav menus, if you're trying to do this with something more custom such as Divi or Elementor you might need to ask for a solution specific to those in their communities rather than here
